# Troubleshooting runtime exceptions when in Design mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

When I open a form, I am suddenly getting an error message:

> "Error reading form: 'X' "
>
> Cache is not initialised. Must call TCache.Initialise first. Ignore the Error and continue? NOTE: Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property values lost"

The "Cache is not initialised" bit is an exception raised by one of our classes.

My first question is, why is the Delphi IDE running my code without me asking it to "Run Program"? What code does it run? Is there any way to turn this off?

Secondly, is there any way I can trap this error in the debugger, so I can work out where in the call stack this exception occurs? I have tried putting a breakpoint where the exception is thrown, but Delphi ignores it.

And also, once I have worked out where this exception is coming from, is there a way to tell when I am in "design mode" and not run that code, or run different code? Or even better, not run that code at all if in design mode?
[Update: See Francois' answer to how to stop code running in design mode.]

Comment: The IDE is not running your code, it is encountering a component which it does not know while reading the .dfm.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. The IDE is displaying the text of an exception thrown by code I wrote. Unless there is some memory corruption, that code must be being run somewhere.

Comment: Well, then your code is in a design time package. Your code has to be run for your component to be instantiated for designing. The only way that I know of to debug is to debug the IDE with another instance of the IDE.

Comment: The error you're describing ("Ignore the error and continue?`) is, as @Sertac said twice, because the IDE is loading the .DFM and couldn't create one of the components it encountered (or found a different version of the design-time package that was missing some property that was stored in the .DFM). It should tell you exactly what the property is, but you omitted that from your quote of the error message. If you can't figure out where it is, post a screen capture of the error dialog. (Design-time packages containing components **are** executed within the IDE at design-time.)

Comment: @Ken I've added the full text of the error dialog.

Comment: OK. So you know the problem is in initializing `TCache`. Is it a component that was on the form (or that was contained by a component on the form)? This is an error caused by streaming in the DFM, and you know which class was involved. Open the .DFM in Notepad or another text editor, and see where `TCache` or the component containing it is located. When the form is being streamed in, an instance of `TCache` is being created, and something is happening that isn't calling it's methods in the proper order. What is it? (I can't see `TCache` from here, so I can't guess.)

Comment: I managed to work out where it was crashing by some deduction and a lot if trial and error. It would be good if there was a better (i.e. quicker and easier) way.

Answer (score 4):

You have some component code that you wrote that is executed when the IDE is trying to load the dfm.

You can test in your code if your component is in "design mode" with

```
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
```

Comment: @Ken This is a different answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KenWhite: ...and your point is? That the flurry of comments/edit were done while I was answering? Thanks, I've got it!

Comment: @François, no offense intended. Didn't know you were a slow typist. <g>

Comment: Once I had worked out the offending component, this did indeed allow me to check for design time and stop running the code that was causing the crash.

Answer (score 4):

When the IDE loads a DFM, it creates live objects within the Form Designer, which means component run-time code is actually run within the IDE.  As such, component code needs to check the `TComponent.ComponentState` property for the `csDesigning` flag if it wants to skip running portions of its code at design-time.